# how to apply kalman filter on HOG Detection in opnecv C++?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tracking, video-processing, kalman-filter

How to apply kalman filter on HOG Detection in opnecv C++??

I want to track the detected object in a video, the detection is done using HOG.
For tracking I want to use Kalman filter so:

- Which parameters of HOG I need to give as an input for Kalman filter?
- And how can I initialize the Kalman filter?

I'm trying to implement it using [OpenCV C++ kalman filter](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d6a/classcv_1_1KalmanFilter.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: afaik kalman filter tracks a "state". In your case this might be something like position, size and velocity

Comment: In my case, the HoG return the coordinates(x,y) of the detected person,so how can i use the   Kalman then

Comment: In my case, the HoG return the coordinates(x,y) of the detected person,

Comment: did you understand opencv kalman tutorials like http://opencvexamples.blogspot.de/2014/01/kalman-filter-implementation-tracking.html ?

Comment: or this http://www.robot-home.it/blog/software/ball-tracker-con-filtro-di-kalman/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494595/multiple-object-tracking-with-kalman-filter